# Problem with diagram "shift" in beamer

Tags: beamer, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

I am having an issue when writing a commutative diagram in Beamer using the `\xymatrix` command.  The diagram is meant to be built piece-by-piece during the presentation.  However, as I move through the slides, pieces of the diagram like to kind of shift around.  It's not much a real problem as it is a potential distraction to members of the audience.  Does anyone know how to fix it?
Notice that the "shifts" occur once pieces that include the `\cdots` show up.  However, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it.

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
\xymatrix{
& & & & & & \uncover<1->{X \ar[dllllll]|-{f_0}} \only<4->{\ar[dlllll]|-{f_1}} \only<9->{\ar@{.>}[dllll]} \only<12->{\ar[dlll]|-{f_k}} \only<17->{\ar@{.>}[dll]} \only<20->{\ar[dl]|-{f_{i-1}}} \only<24->{\ar[dr]|-{\color{red}{f_i}}}\\
\uncover<1->{Y_0} & \only<5->{\ar[l]^{g_0}} \uncover<3->{Y_1} & \only<7->{\ar@{.>}[l] \cdots} & \only<13->{\ar[l]^{g_{k-1}}} \uncover<11->{Y_k} & \only<15->{\ar[l]^{g_k} \cdots} & \only<21->{\ar[l]^{g_{i-2}}} \uncover<19->{Y_{i-1}} & & \only<25->{\ar[ll]^{\color{red}{g_{i-1}}}} \uncover<23->{\color{red}{Y_i}}
}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\visible` instead of `\only`...

Comment: That command wasn't useful.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\pause
\xymatrix{
  & & & & & &
  \uncover<1->{X \ar[dllllll]|-{f_0}}
  \only<4->{\ar[dlllll]|-{f_1}}
  \only<9->{\ar@{.>}[dllll]}
  \only<12->{\ar[dlll]|-{f_k}}
  \only<17->{\ar@{.>}[dll]}
  \only<20->{\ar[dl]|-{f_{i-1}}}
  \only<24->{\ar[dr]|-{\color{red}{f_i}}}\\
  \uncover<1->{Y_0}
  &
  \only<-4>{\ar@{}[l]^{\phantom{g_0}}}
  \only<5->{\ar[l]^{g_0}}
  \uncover<3->{Y_1}
  &
  \only<7->{\ar@{.>}[l]}
  \visible<7->{\cdots}
  &
  \only<13->{\ar[l]^{g_{k-1}}}
  \uncover<11->{Y_k}
  &
  \only<15->{\ar[l]^{g_k}}
  \visible<15->{\cdots}
  &
  \only<21->{\ar[l]^{g_{i-2}}}
  \uncover<19->{Y_{i-1}}
  &
  &
  \only<25->{\ar[ll]^{\color{red}{g_{i-1}}}}
  \uncover<23->{\color{red}{Y_i}}
}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will study and apply what you have done.  Also, I am quite new to posting things on TeX StackExchange.  How do I include the code AND the output like you have?

Comment: @gorzardfu I `convert` PDF to GIF via `convert -delay 50 -density 120 a.pdf a.gif`